# What system color is it used as back-color for the bottom of this window?

Tags: winforms

I'm not interested in the hex code of the color, but its system name, to use in a Form and match the colors in different versions of windows

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That pane is called the "Details Pane", as evident by the menu to show/hide it under Organize > Layout. I don't believe it has a system color since the background is actually an image, which was more obvious in Windows Vista:

[image]

In Windows 7, they just replaced it with a quieter image, leaving only the subtle shadow effect under the top border of the pane. In [this thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/54723-details-pane-customization.html) they discuss changing the image in Windows 7, which further confirms that it is probably an image and not a color.